# JSON array gives empty data even data is present there in ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

On my HTML page I want to display continuous tweets one by one. I have two functions in my script, one load itself and other will be called by first. Below is my code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
(function () {
 $.ajax({
  type:"post",
  url:"fetch_data.php",
  dataType:"json",
  async: false,
  data:{action:'onload'},
  success:function(response){
   $.each(response, function(key, item) {
    var li = '<li><div class="user-pic">'+item.img+'</div><div class="user-details"><h2><span>'+item.name+'</span> @'+item.screen_name+'</h2><p class="cheer-zidane">'+item.tweet+'</p></div></li>';
    $(li).hide().appendTo('.twitter-list').fadeIn('fast');
   });
  }
 });
 setInterval(display_later, 40000);
})();

function display_later() {

 console.log("called display");
 var i = 1;
 $.ajax({
  type:"post",
  url:"fetch_data.php",
  dataType:"json",
  data:{action:'later'},
  success:function(response){
   console.log(response);
    $.each(response, function(key, item) {
     if ( $('.twitter-list li').length == 10) {
      console.log("removed last "+i);
      $('.twitter-list li:last-child').remove();
      i = i + 1;
     }
     var li = '<li class="comefromtop"><div class="user-pic">'+item.img+'</div><div class="user-details"><h2><span>'+item.name+'</span> @'+item.screen_name+'</h2><p class="cheer-zidane">'+item.tweet+'</p></div></li>';
     $('.twitter-list').prepend(li).fadeIn("slow");
    });
  }
 });  
};
```

And fetch_data.php :

```
if($_POST['action'] == 'onload')
{
    //workes fine
}
if($_POST['action'] == 'later')
{
    $j = 0;
    $data1 = array();
    $result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM tweet_mash WHERE is_active = 1 ORDER BY activate_update DESC LIMIT 0,10 ");
    $ispresent = @mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($ispresent > 0)
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            if($row['is_display'] == 0){
                if($row['profile_image']!=""){
                    $img = str_replace("_normal", "", $row['profile_image']);
                    $thumbnail = '<image src="'.$img.'" style="height: 100%;width: inherit;">';
                }else{
                    $thumbnail ="";
                }
                $data1[] = array('img'=>$thumbnail,'screen_name'=>$row['screen_name'],'name'=>$row['name'],'tweet'=>$row['tweet']);
                $update = mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE tweet_mash SET is_display = 1 WHERE id = ".$row['id']." ");
                $j = $j+1;
            }else{
                $j = $j;
            }
        }
        echo json_encode($data1);
        exit;
    }
}
```

**Problem:** When display_later() function is running continuously it hits fetch_data.php. My problem is that even when data is present in mysql db the json array gives empty result. I sure that my code reaches at `if($row['is_display'] == 0){` `$update`(and `$update` reflects in database )

Is my ajax calling is wrong or php code. Please help.

Comment: Any errors in your php error log? Look at the network tab and see what is being sent back. Or do a `console.log(response)` to see.